# Starting React server in VScode takes almost two minutes and does not automatically rerender

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Currently using npm start to start a server takes almost two minutes to get a browser open and when it does open it does not automatically re-render if I change my code. Hitting refresh doesn't work either. I have to shut down the server and wait another two minutes to see the results. Using Yarn results in the same. I have tried many methods to remedy the situation and have zoom chatted with some people but none can find the source of my problem or a remedy. I read that a long PATH could cause problems and mine is definitely long:

```
/home/swade781977/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin:/home/swade781977/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@global/bin:/home/swade781977/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin:/home/swade781977/.nvm/versions/node/v15.10.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Yarn/bin/:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/:/mnt/c/Users/swade/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/swade/AppData/Local/Yarn/bin:/mnt/c/Users/swade/AppData/Roaming/npm:/mnt/c/Users/swade/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/U
```

but I am unsure of how to shorten it. I am using VScode in a WSL shell my file are kept locally. If there is any more information you need to help I will provide it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you using WSL2? If so, it could be that the path is not in the virtual box, this does cause things to go slower.

Comment: I am how would I get the path into the virtual box? Dummy here ( I mean newbie). Thanks

Comment: The recomendation is to put files that you want in WSL2 in your home `cd ~`. The way you can tell is with mounts. Type `mount` and it will show you all the mounts. Usually the windows files are mounted under `/mnt/c/` and will show like this `C:\ on /mnt/c` Anything that is mounted will be slower when dealing with large numbers of files and deeper paths (like web dev calls for)